# Command Line Tool To Supercharge Web Development?

Tags: php

Is there a way to create a command line tool which will help *extensively* in building an application.

For example, say I have a zend project and I want to add a whole new admin module based on some predefined patterns.

I run:

```
$ myzf create admin-module-framework
```

Which would then setup (as per a predefined template):

The module, models, views, controllers, actions, helpers, plugins, and even create a sql file to go with that.

Of course, I wouldn't be looking for something which simply copies certain files to certain directories (I can do that myself). I'd be looking for something which will actually modify the code to fit in with the app (based on some predefined variables).

Possible? Worth the effort?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, that seems like too many 'predefined' dependencies. I just thought it would be even harder to create something more intelligent. Any ideas welcome!

Comment: Many MVC frameworks come with something like this, don't they? I know Cake and Symfony do. Doesn't Zend, too?

Comment: Oh yes, I know Cake has a 'bake' command. But I was looking for something which could be applied to any framework.

Comment: @Pekka, Zend_Tool is available since 1.7 http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.tool.framework.introduction.html

Comment: any framework? that's a monumental effort. scaffolding and code generators, being generic, can at best address only the basic operations needed for any application. unless you look at all applications as "same", you'd probably have to redefine the meaning of "extensive".

Comment: I find Zend_Tool very lacking also. Could it be applied to the above in a single command or would I need to modify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://blog.stuartherbert.com/php/beyond-frameworks/ for a series of articles where Stuart creates such a system.